# Spring mvc folder structure file note found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple problem but I can't figure it out.

When the view resolver sets the suffix and prefix to it displays the page correctly but I have another folder at the same level with WEB-INF folder and when try to change it says not found.

Netbeans displays this folder structure:

```
Mavenproject
└── web pages
    ├── WEB-INF
    │   └── jsp
    │       └── hello.jsp
    └── webapp
        └── newhtml
```

front-controller-servlet.xml (works with /WEB-INF/jsp):

with this controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

private String startmessage="start";

@RequestMapping("form")
public String viewLoginPage(Model model){  
      model.addAttribute("message", startmessage);
    return "hello";


}
```

and now when I change suffix and prefix it doesn't work:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" /> 
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="helloweb" />
```

and controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

private String startmessage="start";

@RequestMapping("form")
public String viewLoginPage(Model model){  
      model.addAttribute("message", startmessage);
    return "newhtml";


}
```

My server says `Grave:   PWC6117: File "null" not found`

Comment: Does the file have the right permissions and ownership to be seen by the process that is looking for it? What OS are you on?